# IDE exception in Android studio on adding a new image asset

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I can't add image asset in Android Studio using the built-in wizard available from the context menu (`New` -> `Image Asset`). I see the following IDE exception every time I try to do that (sorry for very long stack trace below!).

Here is the Android Studio version:

```
Android Studio 3.0
Build #AI-171.4408382, built on October 20, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b08 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.12.6
```

I tried resetting and re-building the IDE cache, but it didn't help.

Here is the error stack trace:

```
Comparison method violates its general contract!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(TimSort.java:777)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:514)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:441)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:245)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1512)
    at java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:348)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at com.android.tools.idea.ui.FileTreeModel.sort(FileTreeModel.java:237)
    at com.android.tools.idea.ui.FileTreeModel.lambda$sort$1(FileTreeModel.java:238)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1251)
    at com.android.tools.idea.ui.FileTreeModel.sort(FileTreeModel.java:238)
    at com.android.tools.idea.ui.FileTreeModel.lambda$sort$1(FileTreeModel.java:238)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1251)
    at com.android.tools.idea.ui.FileTreeModel.sort(FileTreeModel.java:238)
    at com.android.tools.idea.ui.FileTreeModel.lambda$sort$1(FileTreeModel.java:238)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1251)
    at com.android.tools.idea.ui.FileTreeModel.sort(FileTreeModel.java:238)
    at com.android.tools.idea.ui.FileTreeModel.lambda$sort$1(FileTreeModel.java:238)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1251)
    at com.android.tools.idea.ui.FileTreeModel.sort(FileTreeModel.java:238)
    at com.android.tools.idea.ui.FileTreeModel.lambda$sort$1(FileTreeModel.java:238)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1251)
    at com.android.tools.idea.ui.FileTreeModel.sort(FileTreeModel.java:238)
    at com.android.tools.idea.ui.FileTreeModel.lambda$sort$1(FileTreeModel.java:238)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1251)
    at com.android.tools.idea.ui.FileTreeModel.sort(FileTreeModel.java:238)
    at com.android.tools.idea.ui.FileTreeModel.sort(FileTreeModel.java:230)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.assetstudio.wizard.ConfirmGenerateImagesStep.lambda$onEntering$3(ConfirmGenerateImagesStep.java:397)
    at com.android.tools.idea.observable.ListenerManager.receiveAndFire(ListenerManager.java:107)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.assetstudio.wizard.ConfirmGenerateImagesStep.onEntering(ConfirmGenerateImagesStep.java:353)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard.goForward(ModelWizard.java:303)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizardDialog$NextAction.doAction(ModelWizardDialog.java:267)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper$DialogWrapperAction.actionPerformed(DialogWrapper.java:1838)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6541)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6306)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4897)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:827)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:651)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:365)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:736)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:458)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.invokeShow(DialogWrapper.java:1696)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1645)
    at com.android.tools.idea.actions.AndroidAssetStudioAction.actionPerformed(AndroidAssetStudioAction.java:90)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:215)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:232)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:309)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:929)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:136)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:299)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:116)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:86)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransaction$1(TransactionGuardImpl.java:109)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:118)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:122)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:116)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:513)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:45)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:533)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6541)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6306)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4897)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:827)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:651)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:365)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Similar issue was fixed in IDEA core: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-181904. OPlease try to update to AS 3.0.1

Comment: @y.bedrov: thanks, this looks similar to my issue, but unfortunately the only update available for Android Studio is from dev channel (both stable and beta are based on IntelliJ Idea 3.0.0). Not sure if it is usable now.

Comment: @y.bedrov: a short update -- I installed Android Studio 3.1 beta 1 which became available today and I am still seeing the same issue.